# Data Importing from cassandra to solr

Tags: solr, nosql, cassandra

Hello Friends,
              I want to know by any way we can use solr data import handler with cassandra.
If I can get any reference site or example would be good help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at datastax's page on [cassandra integration with solr](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-with-solr-integration-details). Also look at this [Github](https://github.com/tjake/Solandra) repository, its a library for cassandra and solr.

Answer (score 1):

That gitHub library is old , only Datastax Enterprise uses the integration of Cassandra with Solr, but its not free.

You can see Stargate-core soluton for cassandra but it uses lucene
Another one is Stratio Cassandra again it used Lucene

Hope this helps

Regards
Asit